# Shower valve has the screw corroded and I cannot replace it

Tags: shower, valve

[image]My shower valve was falling apart and when I tried to replaced, the internal screw was so corroded that I could not take it out. I tried to use a dangle screw extractor, but it did not work. Please advice about what to do. See the valve in pictures[image]

Comment: What type is the screw head Allen, Phillips, etc.?

Comment: Last resort is reaching in there with a die grinder to grind away the screwhead. Remove too much and you won't have any screw threads left to grab with pliers. Not enough threads, you can drill the screw out and tap new threads or use a helicoil, but it probably makes more sense to replace the valve instead (unless you have taps and/or helicoil tooling laying around).

Comment: What are we looking at in the 2nd pic?

Comment: Screw heads are gone. BTW: I am planning to replace the valve, but that’s the issue, I cannot take it off.